# Golang Json unmarshaling with multiple dynamically named fields

Tags: json, go, struct, unmarshalling, decoding

I have the following Json structure that I need to decode and I'm not sure the proper approach
for unmarshalling it.

```
var b = []byte(`{
    "Card:5417871461137421886": {
        "applicationUUID": "5417871461137421886",
        "commit": "test_commit",
        "lastSeen": "test_lastSeen",
        "localUUID": "E4:F5:13:8E:F5:43",
        "progress": "3.5",
        "externalUUID": "test_externalUUID",
        "state": "test_state"
    },
    "Card:5417871461137421886.Color": {
        "applicationUUID": "5417871461137421886",
        "color": "blue"
    }
}`)
```

My initial approach has been by somehow creating a structure then unmarshalling to the struct, but due to the dynamic nature I'm unsure how to accomplish this. One approach I've tried is using a parallel structure however I have not succeeded at making that work properly also. I'm kind of at a loss for a good way to solve this problem You can see my sample code here https://play.golang.org/p/mzMArgo8ta2

I can not change the structure of the Json because it is being read from an API. Ultimately I do not want or care about the unique field names, since the application ID is always listed as a value. If there would be a simple way to remove all the Card:Id I figure I could just map it like normal.

Comment: It really depends on what you're hoping to get out of it and how you're going to use it. There are a few different approaches

Comment: As @Brits pointed out, the JSON you posted here is substantially different than the one in the Playground; namely, look at the way you identify 'color' in the two examples. Is it a postfix (like here) or a separate entry (like on the Playground)? Also, is the final result _one_ Go object (since both share the same `applicationUUID`) or _two_ different ones? It's not clear which is which, it would be great if you could clarify that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option may be to delay parsing until you know the type; something like the following ([playground](https://play.golang.org/p/QKa8Qnl8XQV)):

```golang
devices := make(map[string]json.RawMessage)

err := json.Unmarshal(b, &devices)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

for key, jsonVal:= range devices {
    if len(key) > 5 && key[:5] == "Card:" {
        var dev Device
        err := json.Unmarshal(jsonVal, &dev)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        fmt.Printf("%#v\n", dev)
    } else if len(key) > 6 && key[:6] == "Color:" {
        var oth Other 
        err := json.Unmarshal(jsonVal, &oth)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        fmt.Printf("%#v\n", oth)
    }
}
```

Note: Its not clear what you want to do with the data so I'm just printing the structs for now. Its also not really clear how to identify the type of each element (the example in your question differs from the example in your sample code); there may be some documentation for the API that explains this?.

Comment: Ultimately it would be used for a data scraper. I can just map the unmarshalled json to a exporter function I have wrote. The problem was originally that I couldn't find a way to map anything because of objects such as Card:ID were unique. For this example printing works just fine but if you have any other suggestions I would love to hear them as I'm extremely new to Go.

Comment: The answer from @StevenPenny will also do the trick; it really depends on the full structure of the file and whether you need to split it into different structs (a bit simpler if you don't). I'd need additional info to make more detailed suggestions but the techniques shown here should get you started (next step is to work out what format the data needs to be in for your next step; e.g. storing in a database etc).

Answer (score 2):

I would do it like this:

```
package main

import (
   "encoding/json"
   "fmt"
)

const s = `
{
   "Card:5417871461137421886": {
      "applicationUUID": "5417871461137421886",
      "commit": "test_commit",
      "externalUUID": "test_externalUUID",
      "lastSeen": "test_lastSeen",
      "localUUID": "E4:F5:13:8E:F5:43",
      "progress": "3.5",
      "state": "test_state"
   },
   "Card:5417871461137421886.Color": {
      "applicationUUID": "5417871461137421886",
      "color": "blue"
   }
}
`

func main() {
   var m map[string]struct {
      ApplicationUUID, Color, Commit, ExternalUUID, LastSeen, LocalUUID string
      Progress, State string
   }
   json.Unmarshal([]byte(s), &m)
   fmt.Printf("%+v\n", m)
}
```

but it seems like a `map[string]map[string]string` would work as well.

Comment: Right, that certainly works if the OP intends to have _two_ different Go entities, as opposed to just one (since both share the same `applicationUUID`).